# Different avatar depending on size

Tags: bug, gravatar

I noticed that my avatar change depending on the size displayed. In the header of the site where the avatar is small the correct image is displayed while in posts and on my user's details another image is shown.

Correct image [image] (48x48)

Gavatar link: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fc4e05bd9d9732e9db5068acf25d3a1d?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

Incorrect image: [image]  (any other resulution)

Gavatar link: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fc4e05bd9d9732e9db5068acf25d3a1d?s=126&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

Comment: For what it's worth, the images in your question look the same to me.